# Importing a groovy file from one package to another groovy file in another package

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

I have a child java project which has groovy files added in classpath using eclipse. Parent java project triggers some functionality in child which uses Groovy library to run the scripts. So `import` works fine in eclipse environment with opened child project but if I run it from command line or if I close child project then I get groovy compilation error at import statement. How can I resolve this ? I want to avoid using `evaluate()` method.

Following is my master groovy:

```
package strides_business_script
abstract class Business_Script extends Script {
//some stuff
}
```

Following is the another groovy:

```
import static strides_business_script.StridesBusiness_Script.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

String Key = Part_Product_PartDetails
boolean containsData = checkIncomingMessage(Key)
if(containsData) {

    def edgeKeyList = [PPR]
    JSONArray partDetails = appendEdgeValueToMsg(edgeKeyList,Key,vertex,messageIterator);
    //deleteMessages(Key);
    JSONObject jsonObject = constructInfoWithPropertyJSON("NAME,PRODUCTTYPE,FGTYPE,UOM,ITEMCLASSIFICATIONBYMARKET");
    jsonObject.put("PARTS",partDetails);
    send(Product_AggPO_ProductDetails,convertJSONToString(jsonObject));

}
```

**Edit:**
My master script `Business_Script.groovy` resides in `scripts/strides_business_script/` folder. All other scripts are in `scripts/StridesComputationScripts/` folder and they import the `Business_Script.groovy`.
I run the application with remote debugging enabled like this:

```
java -cp "./lib/*:./scripts/strides_business_script/Business_Script.groovy" -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=6969,server=y -Dhibernate.cfg.xml.path=./conf/hibernate.cfg.xml -Dlog4j.configuration=file:./conf/log4j.properties com.biglabs.dataExtractor.dataDump.DataDumpDriver 7
```

and here I am trying to parse all computation scripts.

```
for (String scriptName : files) {
                        Script script = groovyShell.parse(new File(
                                SCRIPT_PLACED_AT + Constants.SLASH
                                        + SCRIPT_FILE_FOLDER + Constants.SLASH
                                        + scriptName));
                        scriptMping.put(scriptName, script);
                    }
```

It throws following exception while parsing using groovy shell:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/home/manoj/strides/release/strides/scripts/StridesComputationScripts/PRODUCT-script.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class strides_business_script.StridesBusiness_Script
 @ line 2, column 1.
   import static strides_business_script.Business_Script.*;
   ^

/home/manoj/strides/release/strides/scripts/StridesComputationScripts/PRODUCT-script.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class strides_business_script.StridesBusiness_Script
 @ line 2, column 1.
   import static strides_business_script.Business_Script.*;
   ^

2 errors
```

Comment: How are you building or running it from the command line?  Are you using a tool like Maven or Gradle?

Comment: Build is using maven. And I run it with java -cp from command-line. Tried providing groovy file location as classpath also, but didn't work.

Comment: I have no idea how to reproduce what you have... Could you update your question so that we can try it out?

Comment: Can you post the command line output?

Comment: Please refer the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding script path in comiler configuration:

```
CompilerConfiguration compilerConfiguration = new CompilerConfiguration();
String path = SCRIPT_PLACED_AT;
if(!SCRIPT_PLACED_AT.endsWith("/")){
                        path = path+ "/";
                    }
compilerConfiguration.setClasspath(path);
GroovyShell groovyShell = new GroovyShell(
                            compilerConfiguration);
for (String scriptName : files) {
                        Script script = groovyShell.parse(new File(
                                SCRIPT_PLACED_AT + Constants.SLASH
                                        + SCRIPT_FILE_FOLDER + Constants.SLASH
                                        + scriptName));
                        scriptMping.put(scriptName, script);
                    }
```